# How to retreive data from firestore and fill them in a form for edit (angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

in my angular project based on firebase and firebase i had this form , and when i try to edit a product ,i could access the id of each product but i can't access and fill the form by other data (title,price,category...)
here is my code :
product-form.html

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
  
<form (ngSubmit)="save(f.value)" #f="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="id">Id</label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="product.id"  name="id" type="number" class="form-control" id="id" required #id="ngModel">
        
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="id.touched && id.invalid">The id is required !</div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="product.title"  name="title" type="text" class="form-control" id="title" required #title="ngModel">
        
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="title.touched && title.invalid">Title is required !</div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="price">Price</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="price"  [(ngModel)]="product.price" #price="ngModel" name="price" required min="0">
            <span  class="input-group-text">$</span>
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="price.touched && price.invalid">
            <div *ngIf="price.errors?.['required']">"price is required !"</div>
            <div *ngIf="price.errors?.['pattern']">price must be a number</div>
            <div *ngIf="price.errors?.['min']">price must be =>0 ! </div>
            </div>
    </div> 

     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category">Category</label>
        <select  class="form-control" id="category" [(ngModel)]="product.category" name="category" #category="ngModel" required>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option *ngFor="let category of categories$ " [value]="category.name">{{category.name}}</option>
            </select>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="category.touched && category.invalid">category is required!</div>
        </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="imageUrl">Image Url</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                <span  class="input-group-text">http://</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="imageUrl" #imageUrl="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="product.imageUrl" name="imageUrl" required pattern="https?://.+">
            </div> 
        </div>   
            <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="imageUrl.touched && imageUrl.invalid">
            <div  *ngIf="imageUrl.errors?.['required']">image Url is Required!</div>
            <div *ngIf="imageUrl.errors?.['pattern']">image Url is invalid! must  start with http:// or https://...</div>
        </div>
            <br>
<button class="btn btn-primary"  type="submit">Save</button>
    
</form>

</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
        <img [src]="imageUrl.value" class="card-img-top">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title" style="color: dodgerblue;" >{{title.value}}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">{{price.value | currency:'USD':true}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>

    <div class="toast align-items-center text-white bg-primary border-0" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
        <div class="d-flex">
          <div class="toast-body">
           Product Added succefully
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white me-2 m-auto" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

product-form.ts

```js
import { Component,Inject, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { CategoriesService } from '../../services/categories.service';
import { Router, RouterLink, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/services/product.service';
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/compat/storage';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-products-form',
  templateUrl: './products-form.component.html',
  styleUrl: './products-form.component.css'
})
export class ProductsFormComponent {
  categories$:any;
  products:any
  product$:any;

  private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

  product: any = {
    id: '',
    title: '',
    price: '',
    category:'',
    imageUrl:''
  };


  constructor( categories: CategoriesService,private ProductService :ProductService, private router: Router,private db:AngularFireDatabase, private afs:AngularFirestore ,private route:ActivatedRoute,private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,) 
  {  
    
    this.db.list('/categories').valueChanges().pipe(
      tap(data => {
        this.categories$ = data;
      })
    ).subscribe(
      () => {
        console.log(this.categories$);
      },
    );


    this.afs.collection('/products/').valueChanges().pipe(
      tap(data => {
        this.products = data;
      })
    ).subscribe(
      () => {
        console.log(this.products);
      },
    );

    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'); 
    if (id) {
      console.log(id);
      
    
      this.ProductService.getProductWithKey(id).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe(productData => {
        this.product = productData;
        
        
        console.log(this.product)
        
        
        
      });
  } 





    }


    ngOnInit() {
      const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'); 
      if (id) {
        console.log(id);
        
      
        this.ProductService.getProductWithKey(id).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
        .subscribe(productData => {
          console.log(productData);
          this.product = productData;
        });
      } 

    }


  save(product:any){
    this.ProductService.create(product);
    this.router.navigate(['/admin/products']);
    console.log(product);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }

}
```

Product.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
import {AngularFirestore,AngularFirestoreDocument} from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, take,map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Product } from './Product';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {
  
  product$:any = {};

  constructor(private db:AngularFireDatabase,public afs: AngularFirestore) { 

  }

  create(product:any){
   this.db.list('/products').push(product).then(()=>{console.log(`New product added with ID: ${product.id}`);});
  this.afs.collection('/products').add(product).then(()=>{console.log(`New product added with ID: ${product.id}`);});
  } 

getAll(){
  return this.afs.collection('/products');
}


getProductWithKey(id: string) {
  return this.afs.doc<Product>(`/products/${id}`).snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(action => {
     
      const data = action.payload.data() as Product;
      const title = action.payload.data()?.title;
      const price = action.payload.data()?.price;
      const category = action.payload.data()?.category;
      const imageUrl = action.payload.data()?.imageUrl;
      console.log(action.payload.data()?.title); 
      const id = action.payload.id;
      return { id,title,price,category,imageUrl};
    })
  );
}
}
```

[list of products got from firestore databse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLzc5.png)
[expected when click id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StpC7.png)
[got only id in the form !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWZkS.png)

What i got in the console:
[image]

Comment: are you sure title , price and category are in the database? What are you getting here `console.log(action.payload.data()?.title);`?

Comment: yes they are in databse , and i got undefined in console.log(action.payload.data()?.title);

Comment: @PeterHaddad, since you asked the right questions and OP answered.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your database to the question? Also what does logging `action` give you?

Comment: Here the databse 
https://imgur.com/a/sojaXv9

Comment: what i got in console : 
category: undefined
id: "9"
imageUrl: undefined
price: undefined
title: undefined

Answer (score 0):

The id that you are passing to this method `getProductWithKey(id: string)` should be the `documentId` and not the custom id field that you have in the document fields. For example, you can do the following:

```
  return this.afs.doc<Product>('/products/Fc8xq5nDMbIf0kZJY2AT').snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(action => {
```

This should return the first product that you have created in this list. Or another way is to get all the documents in a collection, for example:

```
 return this.afs.collection<any>('products').snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(actions => actions.map(a => a.payload.doc.data()))
     );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This function says that everything except id might be undefined in some case:

```
getProductWithKey(id: string) {
  return this.afs.doc<Product>(`/products/${id}`).snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(action => {
     
      const data = action.payload.data() as Product;
      const title = action.payload.data()?.title;
      const price = action.payload.data()?.price;
      const category = action.payload.data()?.category;
      const imageUrl = action.payload.data()?.imageUrl;
      console.log(action.payload.data()?.title); 
      const id = action.payload.id;
      return { id,title,price,category,imageUrl};
    })
  );
}
```

So I assume that you caught that case. Also, there might be issue of using undefined in forms. So it would be better to assign null instead of undefined like this for example:

```
const imageUrl = action.payload.data()?.imageUrl ?? null;
```

Also I see you have to subscriptions in which assigns products: one in constructor and one in ngOnInit. It is usually bad practice because in asynchronous code you can't be sure which assignement be first, so I would recommend to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Either You have to pass firestore ID to the below query

```
return this.afs.doc<Product>('/products/Fc8xq5nDMbIf0kZJY2AT').snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(action => {
      const data = action.payload.data() as Product;
      const title = action.payload.data()?.title;
      const price = action.payload.data()?.price;
      const category = action.payload.data()?.category;
      const imageUrl = action.payload.data()?.imageUrl;
      console.log(action.payload.data()?.title); 
      const id = action.payload.id;
      return { id,title,price,category,imageUrl};
    })
```

This Firestore ID should be taken when getting collection DOCS.

OR if the only data in your hand is id:9

Then you should go with **"where" query**.

```
return this.afs.collection('products', ref => ref.where('id', '==', '9').limit(1))
  .doc(id)
  .snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(
    map(action => {
            const data = action.payload.data() as Product;
      const title = action.payload.data()?.title;
      const price = action.payload.data()?.price;
      const category = action.payload.data()?.category;
      const imageUrl = action.payload.data()?.imageUrl;
      console.log(action.payload.data()?.title); 
      const id = action.payload.id;
      return { id,title,price,category,imageUrl};
    })
  );
```

Here Docs with "id" field with "9" is filtered out and,by using LIMIT,datas filtered out is limited to only 1.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys and especially Peter Haddad for the approch

```
    getProductWithKey(id: string) {
  return this.afs.collection<any>('/products').snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(actions => actions.map(a => a.payload.doc.data()))
 );
}
```

and i had to modify the product-form componenet to find the index of selected product in the array

```
 ngOnInit() {
  const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  if (id) {
    console.log(id);
    this.ProductService.getProductWithKey(id).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe(productData => {
        const productId = +id; 
        this.product = productData.find(product => product.id === productId);
  
        console.log(this.product);
      });
  }

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).